# Highlighting newly appended data

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have script similar to this:

```
$.each( data.d, function( index, data ) {
    $("#results").append( data.col1 + ' - ' + data.col2 + '<br />' );
});
```

If this runs the first time, I get 10 rows.  When it runs the second time, it adds another 10 rows to the existing ten rows.  How do I make the newly added 10 rows stand out for a short period of time?

Maybe colour the text red or something then fade out to the default colour without affecting the old 10 rows?

Comment: _"stand out for a short period of time"_  **?!**

Comment: Yes, as in maybe colour the text red or something then fade out to the default colour without affecting the old 10 rows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `delay()` with a class:

```
// Something like this
$cols.addClass('red').delay(2000).removeClass('red');
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I would buffer your output so you only have to mess with the DOM once:

```
var output = [];
$.each( data.d, function( index, conflict ) {
    output.push( data.col1 + ' - ' + data.col2 + '<br />' );
});
$("#results").append(output.join(''));
```

Then what I would do to highlight your newly added DOM elements is add a wrapper around them with a class that I can target later to remove the highlight:

```
var output = [];
$.each( data.d, function( index, conflict ) {
    output.push( data.col1 + ' - ' + data.col2 + '<br />' );
});
$("#results").append('<div class="highlighted">' + output.join('') + '</div>');

var timer = setTimeout(function () {
    $('#results').children('.highlighted').removeClass('highlighted');
}, 5000);
```

And then you would just have a CSS class with a background-color or something set:

```
#results .highlighted {
    background-color : gold;
}
```

Comment: I'm testing this and it works for the first set of results, but not for the 2nd, 3rd and onwards.  For all results after the 1st set of 10, they retain their gold background.

Comment: Can you either post a link to your script, create a JSFiddle, or post more the of relevant code? I'm not sure where/when this code is running. It kinda sounds like there's an error somewhere, because the timeout should work.

Comment: Would it be enough to say (function which creates the results first runs at `$(document).ready`, and then each time a button is clicked.  So when the page loads for the first time, it gets 10 rows, then when the button to get more results is clicked, it appends 10 more rows to the existing results on the screen)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) animation:

```
$.each( data.d, function( index, data ) {
    var $results = $(data.col1 + ' - ' + data.col2 + '<br />');
    $("#results").append($results);
    $results.fadeIn('fast');
});
```

This will start out the new results as invisible and quickly fade them in.

*Note that 'fast' is shorthand for '200ms', or 1/5 of a second. You can put in exact milliseconds or some other shorthand names if you prefer. Also, you can optionally pass an easing (the quality of the fade in) and a callback if you want to do something when the animation is finished.*

Comment: I'm getting an `Object does not support this property of method` error message in IE8.

Comment: @oshirowanen, on what line is it complaining about? This code should work.